# getContentResolver().query with CallLog

Tags: java, android, calllog

I'm working on an Android app. I need to get call log to get info about outcoming calls. I´m using this one (from some topic here):

```
 private void getCallDetails() {

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery( CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null, null,null, null);
int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.NUMBER );
int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.TYPE );
int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DATE);
int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
sb.append( "Call Details :");
while ( managedCursor.moveToNext() ) {
String phNumber = managedCursor.getString( number );
String callType = managedCursor.getString( type );
String callDate = managedCursor.getString( date );
Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
String callDuration = managedCursor.getString( duration );
String dir = null;
int dircode = Integer.parseInt( callType );
switch( dircode ) {
case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
dir = "OUTGOING";
break;

case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
dir = "INCOMING";
break;

case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
dir = "MISSED";
break;
}
sb.append( "\nPhone Number:--- "+phNumber +" \nCall Type:--- "+dir+" \nCall Date:--- "+callDayTime+" \nCall duration in sec :--- "+callDuration );
sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
}
managedCursor.close();
call.setText(sb);
}
```

I can use this newer code too:

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null, null,null, null);
```

but in both examples my app crashes on phone even on emulator. I tried to fix that only think I find out is that this query line is the problem but only with CallLog.
When I use similar code with sms for example everythink is working fine.

```
public StringBuffer getOutgoingSMSContent() {

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent/");
        StringBuffer messagedata = new StringBuffer();
        int count = 0;

        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    messagedata.append("Outgoing message count: " + (count + 1)
                            + "\n");
                    for (int m = 0; m < cursor.getColumnCount(); m++) {
                        if (cursor.getColumnName(m).equalsIgnoreCase("address")
                                || cursor.getColumnName(m).equalsIgnoreCase(
                                        "date")
                                || cursor.getColumnName(m).equalsIgnoreCase(
                                        "body")
                                || cursor.getColumnName(m).equalsIgnoreCase(
                                        "type")) {
                            messagedata.append(cursor.getColumnName(m) + "  : "
                                    + cursor.getString(m));
                            messagedata.append("\n");
                        }
                    }
                    messagedata.append("\n");
                    count++;
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        cursor = null;
        return messagedata;
    }
```

Any idea?

Comment: Look at LogCat and see why you are crashing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this My guess is that you do not have the `READ_CONTACTS` permission, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thought that LogCat is useless now i even know how to use it and i was wrong about that! Yes that was the problem.. Somehow permission for CallLog wasnt enough.

Comment: I have developed a full blown contacts manager application but suddenly when reading CallLogs on Android 5.1 thsi used to happen.